# Change Win8 StyleApp Button and Content Text Color

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I am new to windows UI programming. I am trying to change the border and the content text color of a button from **code** (c++ or c#) not xaml.

So my button looks something like this (white border + white text color by default): [image]

after click on it, I hope both the border and the text color can be changed. It seems that in order to change the color I need to use some `Brush`, but I am not sure how to use it...

Please help share some sample code in C++ or C#. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to change the border of a button :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }
```